# In Tree-sitter grammar, immediate ignores named tokens

Tags: treesitter

Extras are matched as many time as possible between tokens. When this mechanism is not desired for a specific token, the `token.immediate( )` can prevent it. But not if the extra is an external token or a symbol (in other word, a named token).

Imagine a language consisting of consecutive `a`, but when two `a` are not separated by a space, they form a different node.

- `"a a"` gives `(a) (a)`
- `"aa"` gives `(b)`
- `"a aa"` gives `(a) (b)`
- etc...

```js
module.exports = grammar({
  name: 'l',
  extras: $ => [' '],
  rules: {
    source_file: $ => repeat(choice($.a, $.b)),
    a: $ => 'a',
    b: $ => seq(alias($.a, ''), token.immediate('a')),
  }
});
```

This grammar parses input as described, but now, what if I need the extra token `' '` to appear in the output tree. Which is useful when comments are extras but they have to appear in syntax tree in order to be highlighted (usually dimmed).

To achieve such behavior, the extra token must be written as a symbol.

```js
module.exports = grammar({
  name: 'l',
  extras: $ => [$.s],
  rules: {
    source_file: $ => repeat(choice($.a, $.b)),
    s: $ => ' ',
    a: $ => 'a',
    b: $ => seq(alias($.a, ''), token.immediate('a')),
  }
});
```

But then, the `token.immediate( )` no longer works. I have tried with external token as well. It looks like `token.immediate( )` only takes in account inlined regex (which don't appear in output tree).